# How to parse web service data into NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xml-parsing

I am facing a problem in parsing data from a web service response.
I call a web service and get the response as `NSLog`, but I need to capture the data as `NSString`.

Here is my sample code:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:   (NSURLResponse *) response {

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data {
    NSString *strData;
    strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSXMLParser   *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser parse];

    soapResultsString=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    recordResults =YES;
}

 NSString *xmlparserString;
 NSMutableString *soapResultsString;
 bool recordResults;

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString     *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    xmlparserString=elementName;

    if( [xmlparserString isEqualToString:@"ns:return"])
    {
        recordResults =YES;
        soapResultsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 
    if( recordResults )
    {
        [soapResultsString appendString: string];
        NSLog(@"inside%@",string);
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"ns:return"])
    {
        NSLog(@"parser==>%@",parser);
        NSLog(@"nameSpaceUrL==>%@",namespaceURI);
        NSLog(@"qName==>%@",qName);

        NSData *data = [soapResultsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    //   NSLog(@"json==>%@",json);

        NSArray *planArray = [json objectForKey:@"hello_History"];

        NSLog(@"planArrayCount==>%lu",(unsigned long)[planArray count]);
        NSMutableArray *dataSource = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:planArray.count];
        for (int i = 0 ; i<[planArray count]; i++)
        { 
            recordResults = NO;

            txn_id=[[[json valueForKey:@"hello_History"]valueForKey:@"date"]objectAtIndex:i];

            loginId = [[[json valueForKey:@"hello_History"]valueForKey:@"time"]objectAtIndex:i];

        }
    }
}
```

the problem is i getting outputupto this method

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

but my parsing method not at called

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

is there any alternate way to capture the string

Comment: You have posted, code, very nice, but what you actually want, 1. full response in single string? 2. Get full string from `XML` tags in `didEndElement` method? 3. Anything else?

Comment: i got full response in single string.. 2) i need full string from XML tags in didEndElement method, i can't able to parse my string in didEndElement and more over didEndElement not all called i checked through break point is there any alternate way r steps

Comment: You can use your `xmlparserString ` variable in `didEndElement` method, by comparing `elementName` with `xmlparserString`. When this condition goes true, you have full string from `soapResultsString`

Comment: i agree ur answer but my function running upto -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string after that i function not calling didEndElement method

Comment: can you post your xml string response or part of it?

Comment: i can't post my response dude its confeditinal

Comment: Just alter the values and keys, post the format. And point the key ,you want value of.